# Expression to validate the required field

Tags: java

Below is the method to throw the exception if the amount is not integer or float
but when I pass string forcefully it does not work , as in case of string it should throw the exception and make the valid as false but it still return the valid as true please advise what is wrong in my expression below

```
private boolean isAmount(String amount) {
    boolean isValid = true;
    try {
        if (amount.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"))  {
            return isValid;     
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not trying to convert it anywhere, so no exception thrown. Just do this...

```
private boolean isAmount(String amount) {
    return amount.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex works just fine, it is the logic around it that is not working:

This will work:

```
private boolean isAmount(String amount) {
  if(amount == null) return false;
  if (amount.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+")) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Or something like this:

```
private boolean isAmount(String amount) {
  boolean ret = true;
  try {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(amount);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    ret = false;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: The first solution could be reduced to `return amount != null && amount.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"));`.

Comment: You are correct, however, I prefer a more verbose approach to coding.  One of the places I worked demanded it, others preferred it.  It is surprising the number of developers could not decode what you wrote but could with what I wrote.  Still +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
   // Try this one to check the output - running fine.... as per your needs

    private boolean isAmount(String amount) {
    boolean isValid = true;
    try {
           if (amount.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"))  {
           isValid= true; 
}   
else
{
 isValid = false;
}

}catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
    }
```